# What is the difference between different generation processors with the same clock speed when talking about PHP code execution?

Tags: php, performance, optimization, cpu, processors

I am currently in my final year of a compsci uni course, and am doing a web dev module.

We have to write a PHP script to process a large data file and our score is based on our benchmarked time.

My PC has an i5-4460 @ 3.4GHz.
The benchmark PC has an i3-4130 @ 3.4GHz.

Will the code be a similar execution time across both of them? Or will the i3 perform slower.

Just want to get an idea of the time I can expect on the benchmarking system so I can optimise further if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Processor speed is one small factor. Memory speed and disk speed may be more significant. Ultimately, your script's performance will have more to do with the algorithm you use and the code you write to implement it. Start there.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Thanks. My code already takes almost half the time for the best score, so I'm happy with how it runs on my PC. I just wanted to double-check to see if that would be indicative of the performance on the other CPU.

Comment: The only way to get a meaningful answer to that is to run it on the other PC and compare the results.

Comment: On CPU level i3-4130 will perform a bit slower. With near the equal single thread perfomance i5-4460 can utilize 6 MB Intel® Smart Cache when i3-4130 only 3 MB Intel® Smart Cache.

Answer (score 1):

Can you decide which PHP version the benchmark will run on? And is OPcache enabled?

If so target PHP 8.0 and utilize the JIT compiler which runs on x86 CPUs (i.e. Intel/AMD).

Other micro optimisations is using the fully qualified name of the function if you are in a namespace as certain functions are special cased by the VM.

However, your algorithm will always be the bottleneck and if you can improve that you'll get better results than doing tiny language config optimizations.

So benchmark often and try to reduce the big O notation cost. :-)